# TDD and resources freeing

Tags: java, unit-testing, tdd

I tried to use TDD and got following code:

```
public class ViewModel extends BaseObservable {

    private final Subscription subscription;

    public ReleasesViewModel(Observable<List<Data>> model) {

        subscription = model.subscribe(this::setData);       
    }

    public void destroy() { //method is not under test 
        subscription.unsubscribe();       
    }

    public List<Data> getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(List<Data> data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```

and my test for :

```
public class ViewModelTest {

    @Test
    public void getData() {

        BehaviorSubject<List<Data>> observable = BehaviorSubject.create();
        ViewModel viewModel = new ViewModel(observable);

        List<Data> dataList = Arrays.asList(mock(Data.class), mock(Data.class));
        observable.onNext(dataList);

        assertTrue(viewModel.getData().equals(dataList));
    }
}
```

The question is following:

I should verify that `subscription.unsubscribe();` will be called to release resources, I can wrap subscription in some wrapper and inject dependency via constructor but I feel like I can violate an encapsulation of `ViewModel` class. After a lot of googling I did not find any clue for the case of verifying memory releasing in TDD practice. Can some one point me to some "best practices" for this case.

Comment: Why would passing in `Subscription` in the constructor violate encapsulation - it is already a member of your `ViewModel` class? How is it being injected in your current code if not through the constructor?

Comment: Sorry, was little mistake in code.
I obtain "subscription" from "model" passed via constructor.

Comment: Why does `Subscription` have to go inside the inside the `ViewModel`?

Comment: Subscription declares a logic of fetching data from observable model in "subscribe" method and puts the data via setter to the view model. The logic can not be implemented outside the view model.

Comment: *`assertTrue(viewModel.getData().equals(dataList));`* you test the internal data handling of you viewModel class. *this* is a violation of encapsulation.

Comment: Sorry, @TimothyTruckle, testing of public method can't violate encapsulation.

Comment: @DmitryBykov *"testing of public method can't violate encapsulation"* It is not the test, but having a  *getter* on a class which is not a DTO that violates the encapsulation. The use of that getter in the test just makes it hard to fix that.

Comment: Ok, @Timothy Truckle, thanks, maybe you have some example of proper mvvm testing, especially if some reactive extensions is used(rxJava, Rx.NET)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> maybe you have some example of proper mvvm testing

This is what I'd do using Mockito (Just my preference, any other Mocking Framework will do either...):

```
public class ViewModelTest {
    @Rule
    public MockitoRule rule = MockitoJUnit.rule();
    @Mock
    BehaviorSubject<List<Data>> observable;
    @Mock
    Subscription subscription;
    List<Data> data = Collections.emptyList();

    @Test
    public void Constructor_CalledWithObservable_subcribesSetDataMethod() {
        // prepare
        when(model.subscribe()).thenRetun(subscription);

        // act
        ViewModel viewModel = new ViewModel(observable);

        // assert
        verify(observable).subscribe(ViewModel::setData);
    }

    @Test
    public void destroy_unsubscribes() {
        // prepare
        when(model.subscribe()).thenRetun(subscription);    
        ViewModel viewModel = new ViewModel(observable);

        // act
        viewModel.destroy();    

        // assert
        verify(subscription).unsubscribe();
    }
}
```

Comment: And what do you do in case of you have to transform the observer inside  view model with .cache() or .delay() or other methods?
For example:
ViewModel(Observable observable){
subscription = model.cache().subscribe(this::setData);

Comment: @DmitryBykov Don't understand that. What is the *business related behavior* behind that call? What I mean is that how `model` stores the `observable` is an implementation detail that should not be tested. What you *may* test is that `subscribe(this::setData)` is only called once (what the verify method already does...)

Comment: I'm talking about cases like this, when you can't mock observable 
parameter in constructor

`public ViewModel(Observable<String> names){
      subscription = names.filter(name -> name.contain("Jon")).subscribe();
}`

Comment: *`public ViewModel(List<Observable<String>> names){ subscription = names.filter(name -> name.contain("Jon")).subscribe(); }`* pass in a real List with a mocked `Observable`, tell the observable to return the name in question and verify that `subscribe()` is called on the mock...

Comment: I can't verify that 'subscribe()' is called on the mock because I don't know which method will be called(if at all) on observable 'names' in constructor.

Comment: @DmitryBykov *"I don't know which method will be called"* isn't that your code you're testing? how come you don't know how the code should interact with its dependencies?

Comment: Yes!, @Timothy, you are awesome! I've got it! I should put interaction with dependencies under testing and it is the real way I make test works for me and even if some one will do any work with passed observable he will have to change tests - it is the only way to verify that subscription unsubscribes. Thank you one more time for your response and your time!